# Cannot nest $ under $in with decimal number in mongo query by using spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

We have a mongo query which is executed properly in robo mongo for finding a list of bigdecimal value, but I'm not able to create the java code for the same.

I have tried to use the `$numberDecimal` in `$in` operator by using java code but it doesn't work and giving me this error:

> Cannot nest $ under $in with decimal number in mongo query by using
>   spring boot

So I was able to generate this type query but it is giving me error:

```
db.getCollection("").aggregate({[
    "$match": {
        "$and" : [{ "xxx" : 
            {$in: [ {  "$numberDecimal" : "1235.000" 
} ] }} ]} ]})
```

And this one is working:

```
db.getCollection("").aggregate({[
    "$match": {
        "$and" : [{ "xxx" : 
            {$in: [ {  NumberDecimal("1235.000" )
} ] }} ]} ]})
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to do anything , when we create query through spring boot/java code

```
db.getCollection("").aggregate({[
    "$match": {
        "$and" : [{ "xxx" : 
            {$in: [ {  "$numberDecimal" : "1235.000" 
} ] }} ]} ]})
```

like query work when it hit to database.

Comment: This saved so much of my time.  Have some upvotes!